# Angular JS expression not evaluating using $http service

Tags: angularjs

This is Script.js

```
var app = angular
.module("myModule", [])
.controller("myController", function ($scope, $http) {
    $http.get(   
           url: 'EmployeeService.asmx/GetAllEmployees'
           )
          .then(function (response) { 
              $scope.employees = response.data;
           });
});
```

This is Htmlpage1.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.7.8/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/Script.js"></script>


</head>
<body ng-app="myModule">
    <div ng-controller="myController">
        <table border="1" style="border:none;">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Id</th>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Gender</th>
                    <th>Salary</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr ng-repeat="employee in employees">
                    <td>{{employee.id}}</td>
                    <td>{{employee.name}}</td>
                    <td>{{employee.gender}}</td>
                    <td>{{employee.salary}}</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</html>

    The expression Id   Name    Gender  Salary
    {{employee.id}}     {{employee.name}}   {{employee.gender}}     {{employee.salary}} is not getting evaluated

   The values of the table are not displaying
```

Comment: do `console.log` your http response and share the logs with us as well.

Comment: @FarhatZaman nothing happens...not getting the logs

Comment: can you check your network tab to see that is service hitting and getting response successfully or not? if service is not hitting properly then it means that service url is wrong.

Comment: @FarhatZaman Getting 304 not modified  status code

Comment: Here i m using microsoft visual studio 2017 software

Comment: HTTP 304 has nothing to do with Angular I suppose, it's Browser behavior.Add a random query string behind your url, that takes timestamp as the value. This way, each request will be considered a fresh one.

Comment: `url: 'EmployeeService.asmx/GetAllEmployees' + '?_=' + new Date().getTime() `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What event or who is making that request?

```
   var app = angular
   .module("myModule", [])
   .controller("myController", function ($scope, $http) {

       //when the page is ready
       angular.element(document).ready(function() {
           $http({ method: 'GET',
                   url: 'EmployeeService.asmx/GetAllEmployees'
           }).then(function (response) { 
                 $scope.employees = response.data;
           }).catch(function (err) {
               console.log('Error encountered : ' + err);
           });
       });           
});
```

Answer (score 1):

`$http.get()` method gets the url parameter as a string, so you are not using it correctly. This is the correct syntax:

```
$http.get('EmployeeService.asmx/GetAllEmployees')
```

Read more: [$http#get](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#get)

IF the url is correct then your code should work with this change